# Creating an arrow for a div in css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i am trying to create a small arrow for a div box , like this: [image]

I got my pictures to overlap but i have no idea how to create that small arrow which points to the big picture

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="imageDiv"></div>
        <div class="imageDiv bottomDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageDiv {
    margin-top: 70px;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 555px;
    height: 455px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.bottomDiv {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 460px;
    left: 404px;
    width: 295px;
    height: 295px;
    background: black;
}
```

Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aw8RD/1853/)

Any help on creating this would be great, Also i am using bootstrap for mobile responsive , and i was also wondering when the screen gets smaller would it be a better idea to move the yellow box below the picture? or just make everything smaller? iam pretty sure i will use media queries but haven't decided what to do yet

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may try using a rotated square with **:before** (or :after) element like this :

```css
.imageDiv {
  margin-top: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 555px;
  height: 455px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.bottomDiv {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 460px;
  left: 404px;
  width: 295px;
  height: 295px;
  background: black;
}
.imageDiv.bottomDiv:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 25px;
    left: -15px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="imageDiv"></div>
    <div class="imageDiv bottomDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and for small screen you can do this :

```css
.imageDiv {
  margin-top: 70px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 455px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.bottomDiv {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 460px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 150px;
    background: black;
}
.imageDiv.bottomDiv:before {
   content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="imageDiv"></div>
    <div class="imageDiv bottomDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RonTheOld and when the screen get smaller it's better to make the caption on the image but at the bottom, so like it will hide a part of the bottom image and it will take full width

Comment: @RonTheOld updated my anwser to give you a suggestion for small screen (just use this code inside you media query)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (well, change the colors, positioning and size as needed):

```
.bottomDiv:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 20px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
    left: -20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aw8RD/1855/

Comment: Perfect, and i guess i would just use media queries to put that div below the pic after?

Answer (score 2):

Creating an arrow like that with CSS is just adding border to something with 0 width/height, and use the pseudo-element ::before to "attach" the arrow to the left of the desired element.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

```
<div class="arrow-left"></div> 

.arrow-left::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```