# CSS "Arrow" On Side of Box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically I'm trying to do essentially the same thing as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692886/creating-an-arrow-for-a-div-in-css), however, I'm using a background image instead of a flat background color.

I've previously tried "the border method" but that doesn't come out right. In my fiddle, I tried using a technique that creates a rotated square (diamond) on the edge. In both cases the background is off because of said background image:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```css
body {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.journey-boxes {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.journey-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.journey-box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
}

.journey-box-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/20");
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.journey-box-header:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  right: -15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.journey-box-header h4 {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.journey-box-body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="journey-boxes">
  <!-- Week One -->
  <div class="journey-box">
    <div class="journey-box-container">
      <div class="journey-box-header">
        <h4>Week One</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="journey-box-body">
        <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Week Two -->
  <div class="journey-box">
    <div class="journey-box-container">
      <div class="journey-box-header">
        <h4>Week Two</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="journey-box-body">
        <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Given the code in your question, I don't see an issue with the border being pushed out like in your screenshot. Please upload the image you use as a background to the question and then insert it into the `background-image` property's URL value, and review any other missing properties in order to create a [mcve].

Comment: It's really strange, your question does not contain any questions. It works very well. what is the question ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Their problem statement is "*In both cases the background is off because of said background image:*" As you can see from the image, there is space between the colored background and the right edge of the div container that should not be there. The problem does not occur in the Stack Snippet, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second counter rotate to the element, to make the background align again. Is this what you are looking for?

```css
body {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}

.journey-boxes {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.journey-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.journey-box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
}

.journey-box-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/20");
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.arrow{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  right: -15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: inherit;
}

.arrow::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-5px);
  background: inherit;
}

.journey-box-header h4 {
  letter-spacing: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.journey-box-body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="journey-boxes">
  <!-- Week One -->
  <div class="journey-box">
    <div class="journey-box-container">
      <div class="journey-box-header">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <h4>Week One</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="journey-box-body">
        <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Week Two -->
  <div class="journey-box">
    <div class="journey-box-container">
      <div class="journey-box-header">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <h4>Week Two</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="journey-box-body">
        <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```